# Bochner-Type Theorem for MGF

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

Bochner's Theorem characterizes the the Fourier transform of a positive finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. This tells us, in principle, which functions can be characteristic function of a random variable. Is there any result that characterizes the (bilateral) Laplace transforms of measures on $\mathbb{R}$? That is, a way to determine whether a given function can be the moment generating function of a random variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem#Existence

Comment: I've heard this called "Widder's Theorem"; I think a version is in a book by Akhieser:  If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, and every matrix of form $(f(x_i + x_j))_{i,j}$ is positive semi-definite, then there is a measure $\mu$ such that $f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} \exp(ux) \mu(du)$.  If also $f(0)=1$ then $\mu$ is a probability measure.  The converse is trivial.

Comment: See theorem 4 in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82556481.pdf for a statement and proof.  I dont have time to track down an original reference.